# How I Make Static Dropdown in Laravel and How I Make Controller o Select

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Here is My Code and Everything...

in My Dropdown Ther is Three types of log

**Logs.Blade.PHP FILE**

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-7">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h3>Select Log Type</h3>
                                    <form name="logs" method="post" id="logs_select">

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <select class="selectpicker" name="log_picker"
                                                        data-style="form-control btn-secondary">
                                                    <option value="error_log">Error Log</option>
                                                    <option value="access_log">Access Log</option>
                                                    <option value="sys_log">System Log</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <button type="submit"
                                                        class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light m-r-10">
                                                    Submit
                                                </button>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Here is Image of Output:**

[image: Here the Screenshot of Project]

**Here is The Image of Controller :**

[image]

Now I want to make when user click on submit it will display particular log which I code from controller or i.e user select error log and click on submit so, there is on select I need to call something which display error logs.

Please anyone can help I stuck in this error for 2 days but don't find any ways. I am still confused in laravel. in PHP this thing is easy but in laravel Implementation could be heavy for me.

Comment: You could add a hidden input field that contains the server_id. When the form is posted to another controller function, you can fetch the specific log for that server and inject it into another view to display it

Comment: it means If user select error log then I pass the error_log in url?

Comment: @Thomas' right. have your controller generate random code prefixed with different logs you got. put them as input value of type hidden. and send em over toward a different controller or may be route request as POST.